# How to run .sql file using sqlplus from powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell, sqlplus

I am trying to run a .sql file form powershell as :-

```
sqlplus username/password@TnsAlias 'c:\path\to\DBscript.sql'
```

Here TnsAlias refers to my ORACLE_SID

Whenever i run this command, i get the standard usage instructions of sqlplus.

Could someone help me out on this.

I am running this on Windows Server 2012 and Powershell version 4.0,if it helps.

Comment: try test connection without sqlfile `sqlplus username/password@TnsAlias`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
PS M:\> sqlplus scott/tiger@kc11g "@m:\dbscript.sql"

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ╚et Kol 16 07:59:25 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options


    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: I am using Oracle 12.1.0.2.0
Do you think that might be a reason for it not running

Comment: I'm not sure whether you noticed the difference in the way you called the SQL script and the way I did it. Should be `"@m:\dbscript.sql"`. I don't think that difference in database version has anything to do with it.